# why for loop can initialize variable passed by value in Java

Tags: java, oop, for-loop, reference

Code:

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

class Heapify {
  int[] array;

  Heapify (int[] array){
   this.array = array;
  }


  public  void heap (int[] aArray){
    int left = 0;
    int right  = aArray.length - 1;
    int n = aArray.length;
    int numOfSwap  = 0;    
    heapify1(aArray, left, right, numOfSwap );  
  }  


  public void heapify1 (int[] aArray, int left, int right, int numOfSwap) {
    //from last one that have a child
    for (int i = (right - 1)/2; i > left - 1;  --i){  
      System.out.println("in heapify for loop with i =  " + i + "    number of swap: " + numOfSwap);
      if (aArray[2*i + 2] > aArray[i]) {//if right child is bigger than parent
        System.out.println("in heapify for loop and if #1: " + numOfSwap);
        swap(aArray, i, 2*i + 2, right, numOfSwap);
      }
      else if (aArray[2*i + 1] > aArray[i]){
        System.out.println("in heapify for loop and else if #2: " + numOfSwap);
        swap(aArray, i, 2*i + 1, right, numOfSwap);
      }
    }
  }


  public int swap (int[] aArray, int parent, int child, int right, int numOfSwap ){
    System.out.println("in swap before: " + numOfSwap );
    int temp = aArray[parent];
    aArray[parent] = aArray[child];
    aArray[child] = temp;
    numOfSwap  = numOfSwap  + 1;
    System.out.println("inswap after: " + numOfSwap );
    heapify1 (aArray, parent, right, numOfSwap );
    return numOfSwap;
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] array1 = new int[] {21,15,25,3,5,12,7,45,19,2,9};

    Heapify hs = new Heapify(array1);
    hs.heap(array1);
  }
}
```

The result printed value was:

```
in heapify: 0
in heapify for loop with i = 4    number of swap: 0
in heapify for loop and if #1: 0
in swap before: 0
inswap after: 1
in heapify: 1
in heapify for loop with i = 4    number of swap: 1
in heapify for loop with i = 3    number of swap: 0
in heapify for loop and if #1: 0
in swap before: 0
inswap after: 1
in heapify: 1
in heapify for loop with i = 4    number of swap: 1
in heapify for loop with i = 3    number of swap: 1
in heapify for loop and else if #2: 1
in swap before: 1
inswap after: 2
in heapify: 2
in heapify for loop with i = 4    number of swap: 2
in heapify for loop with i = 3    number of swap: 2
in heapify for loop with i = 2    number of swap: 0
in heapify for loop with i = 1    number of swap: 0
in heapify for loop and else if #2: 0
```

I do not understand that why `swap` passed `numOfSwap = 1` to `heapify1`, but in the for loop, the second time of the iteration, `numOfSwap` was overwritten with value 0. Also why in the later case, such behavior of overwritten happened at 3rd iteration?

I know this might be the issue of  “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”, but the **one thing that really confuse me is that the numOfSwap got updated from 0 to 1 in the swap, swap calls heapify1 again passing the numOfSwap = 1 to heapify1 successfully. But why numOfSwap get initialized in the for loop after iterations?**

Comment: Your code could not compile. `swapTimes` in `heapify1` method is not defined. And the code cannot produce your output. There is no where "in heapify:" can be print, for example.

Comment: @TKJohn sorry about typo. corrected and now it compiles and runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different kinds of context of `heapify1` method.

One is when calling `heapify1(aArray, left, right, numOfSwap );` in `heap` method. In this context, the `numOfSwap` is 0, and keeps 0. And it is in this context, where the `for` loop is performed. It may looks like "numOfSwap get initialized in the for loop after iterations?", but it's not true. The value is never modified and keeps 0.

The other context is when calling `heapify1 (aArray, parent, right, numOfSwap );` in `swap` method, so to say " swap calls heapify1 again passing the numOfSwap = 1 to heapify1 successfully". But these passed values are used just in this context, and has no relevant of the first context mentioned, and won't modify the value of `numOfSwap` which is 0.

Comment: @Bighuyou rewroted

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I still don't find your answer explains following output:    5th line to 8th lines of output.   Apparently in the method swap, it calls heapify with passing NumOfSwap = 1, resulting in heapify the NumOfSwap is 1. but later on it just get overwritten to initial value

Comment: ohh, do you mean that when the NumOfSwap get initialized, it means the iteration jumped out of the previous iteration which called swap and added 1 to NumOfSwap, so now it went back to the heapify that was called by heap?

Comment: @Bighuyou You return the value but do nothing with it. The `numOfSwap` in `swap` is local to `swap`: the value in `heapify1` isn’t being "overwritten", it simply hasn’t changed, because you’re talking about two different values.

Comment: @DaveNewton I would like to make sure if my following understanding is correct: when I called `swap` from`heapify` with `i = 4`, the `numOfSwap`  got  + 1 in the `swap`, then swap call `heapify` with `numOfSwap ++` but when we got out of that iteration where `i = 4`, `heapify` went back to the `heapify` called by `heap' with `NumOfSwap = 0`? thanks!

Comment: @Bighuyou I think what you're saying is correct. The value of `numOfSwap` in `heapify1` is unaffected by any changes made by other methods. Java is pass-by-value, here an integer, and a change made to a parameter value is not reflected in the caller. Note that if you pass the value of an object reference you can change object properties that *would* affect the caller, but you're not passing an object. If you passed an object, say `obj1`, and wrote `obj1 = foo` in the called function, that would not be reflected in the caller. If you wrote `obj1.setFoo(whatever)` the caller would see the change